# How to find an element with custom attributes using Xamarin UI Test FWK

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am automating a test case using Xamrain UI Test FWK(Xamarin Test Cloud) in c#.

I have element like below:

```
 <Button gen-id="1234">....</Button>
```

I want to tap on the above button which does not have "ID" and "Class" attributes to that. 
I tried with below code but it does not worked for me.

```
Xamarin.UITest.Android.AndroidApp.Tap(c => c.Property("gen-id", "1234"));
```

Can any one, Please help me on this issue.

Comment: How you are adding custom "attributes" without subclassing the control and thus not causing exceptions at the time of inflating the XAML?

Comment: This is already existing application and it is not developed using Xamarin, it is a hybrid application developed using normal HTML5. In an HTML file  I have initialized this custom attribute. Now I am using Xamarin UI Test FWK to develop Automation test cases for this application.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to edit prev code of Button then try inheriting it from a custom interface like below:

```
interface CustomAttribute
{
     string gen_id{get;set;}
}
```

Now use the inherited button class and set `gen_id` tag.
In MainActivity of .droid project add following:

```
Xamarin.Forms.Forms.ViewInitialized += (object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ViewInitializedEventArgs e) =>
{
        (e.View is CustomAttribute &&  !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((e.View as CustomAttribute ).gen_id))
            {
                e.NativeView.SetTag ("gen-id", (e.View as CustomAttribute ).gen_id);
            }
};
```

Now you should be able to find gen-id in Test project. (I haven't tested and run this code)

Comment: Hi Vishnu, Code you have provided is to add the custom attribute to the view. But I already have an element with custom attribute in my view. My question here is I want find that button with custom attribute(gen-id) in the Xamarin UI Test FWK.

Comment: Can you print [all elements](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.UITest.Queries.AppQuery/) and their properties (or Raw string of each element) to check if attribute "gen-id" is appearing? If not, use above code to get "gen-id" as property in element then the query on Property can work.

Comment: I am able to print all the elements using the code app.Query(c => c.All()); and I am able to see "gen-id" in the DOM , But I need query the element with "gen-id=1234" using Xamarin Test FWK.  How can I do that?